# Absolute value notation in $\lvert\,x\,\rvert$

Tags: absolute-value

I know that $\lvert x\rvert < 1$ can be rewritten as $-1 < x < 1$
What about $\lvert x\rvert > 1$? Can this also be rewritten as $-1 < x < 1$?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consider $x=0$, which has $-1 < x < 1$ but not $\lvert\,x\,\rvert > 1$.

$\lvert\,x\,\rvert > 1$ can be written as "$x < -1$ or $1 < x$".

Answer (score 0):

1. Draw the graph of $y=|x|$.
2. Identify on the $y$-axis the region corresponding to $y>1$, i.e. $|x|>1$.
3. Project horizontally to a region on the graph (first pair of arrows).
4. Project said region vertically to the $x$-axis (second pair of arrows).
5. Identify the solutions: $x < -1$ or $x > 1$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No.  Recall that $|x|$ is defined piecewise by
$$|x| := \begin{cases}
x & \text{if $x \ge 0$, and} \\
-x & \text{if $x < 0$.}
\end{cases} $$
Examining the first inequality, i.e. $|x| < 1$, with respect this definition, we have two cases to consider:  either $x \ge 0$, or $x < 0$.  In the first case, we conclude that
$$ (|x| = x < 1 \ \text{and}\  0 \le x) \implies 0 \le x < 1. $$
In the second case, we have
$$ (|x| = -x < 1 \implies x > -1 \ \text{and}\ 0 > x) \implies -1 < x < 0.$$
Since either of these cases holds, we get that $-1 < x < 0$ or $0 \le x < 1$, which can be written more concisely as
$$ -1 < x < 1. $$

In dealing with the inequality $|x| > 1$, we can't really make the same simplifications.  In the case that $x \ge 0$, we have
$$ |x| = x > 1, $$
and in the case that $x < 0$, we hvae
$$ |x| = -x > 1 \implies x < -1.$$
Again, either case could hold, so we have
$$ x < -1 \ \text{or}\ x > 1.$$
There really isn't any shorthand that makes this easier to write (at least, not without using interval notation which, honestly, is probably the right way to go).